# In table of contents, long page numbers intrude on right margin despite plenty of available space

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, tocloft

Some of the page numbers listed in my table of contents are long roman numerals. For some reason, these long page numbers get pushed into the right margin.

Here is a screenshot of the table of contents. Note that the "xviii" page number gets pushed into the right margin, creating a black "warning blot".

[image: Abstract's page number violates right margin]

How can I fix this? Below is some minimal code that recreates this problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

% PROBLEM: In the table of contents here, the abstract's page number is pushed
%          into the right margin.
\tableofcontents
\newpage .

\section*{Acknowledgements}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}

Here are the acknowledgements.

% a bunch of blank pages, to place the abstract on page xviii
\newpage . \newpage . \newpage . \newpage . \newpage .
\newpage . \newpage . \newpage . \newpage . \newpage .
\newpage . \newpage . \newpage . \newpage . \newpage .

\chapter*{Abstract}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

This is the abstract.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try in the preamble `\makeatletter
\def\@pnumwidth{50pt}\makeatother`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) provides `\cftsetpnumwidth{<len>}` which sets the value of `\@pnumwidth` to `<len>`, so you could just execute

```
\cftsetpnumwidth{3em}% 3em width for page numbers
```

*after* loading `tocloft` (see **2.3 Typesetting the entries**, p 8 of the [`tocloft` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf)):

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Increase the space reserved to typeset the page number; add to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{1cm}
\makeatother
```

and instead of `1cm` use a suitable length.

Your example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,letterpaper]{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{1cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section*{Acknowledgements}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}

\newpage

\setcounter{page}{18}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

This is the abstract.

\end{document}
```

now produces

[image]

Comment: Best answer IMO as it does not need an external package. For me, `{2em}` works well for page numbers up until three digits.