# Page numbers in TOC become flush left when \thepage is changed

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, koma-script, page-numbering

I would like to prepend the page numbers in my `scrbook` with a letter and a hyphen. This works well for the page footers by redefining `\thepage`. However, the page numbers get aligned left instead of right in the TOC.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}       % flush right page entries in TOC
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{P-\Roman{page}}    % flush left page entries in TOC
\clearpage\section{Sec1}
\clearpage\section{Sec2}
\end{document}
```

Correct alignment:
[image]

Incorrect alignment:
[image]

Can I somehow fix the alignment for the prepended page numbers?

Comment: Also related: [In table of contents, long page numbers intrude on right margin …](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53595/in-table-of-contents-long-page-numbers-intrude-on-right-margin-despite-plenty-o)

Comment: Thanks! The solutions to the linked questioned worked. – Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: A minor thing to not is that @CL (OP of `Right justify roman page numbers in list of tables`) mentioned that the problem only occurred in the LOT, but not in the TOC.