# How to find and remove an "Overfull \hbox"

Tags: errors, warnings, badness

In my log output I get the following 5 warnings:

```
Overfull \hbox (1.18692pt too wide) detected at line 81
 []\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 100

\hbox(6.90094+0.0)x16.97252
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 1
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0


Overfull \hbox (1.18692pt too wide) detected at line 82
 []\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 100

\hbox(6.90094+0.0)x16.97252
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 1
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0


Overfull \hbox (1.18692pt too wide) detected at line 83
 []\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 100

\hbox(6.90094+0.0)x16.97252
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 1
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0


Overfull \hbox (1.18692pt too wide) detected at line 84
 []\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 100

\hbox(6.90094+0.0)x16.97252
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 1
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0
.\T1/lmr/m/sc/10.95 0

)
\tf@toc=\write5

\openout5 = `output.toc'.
```

I tried to solve this warnings, but I cannot find where these overfull \hboxes are. On lines 80-84 there is no text in my texfile. Now I removed some text from my source file (around 150 pages) in order to identify where the 5 warnings come from. I managed to make them disappear by deleting some random parts of my text, but this did not answer my question. Also deleting some completely other random text, could remove the warnings. And this included lines which clearly did not produce a bad box. Because of this strange behaviour I cannot provide a minimal working example. Maybe you can tell me from my log file where the warnings come from. I am sure that there are no particular lines in my tex which produce these warnings, but it is more a global error coming from my settings.

[image: I could identify the overfull box:]

Comment: since it's in small caps and the same on every page I would guess it is your page header

Comment: add \showoutput  to your document then you will see the full box contents, also you have not shown enough of your log file to see _which file_ the line 83 is referring to.

Comment: I used \showoutput and updated the question including the new information.

Comment: Add `\overfullrule=5pt` and look for the black swatches?

Comment: I found the problem with \overfullrule. It is in the table of contents and appears as soon as I reach 100 pages. The now three instead of two digits are the problem I guess. But the section title is short, there would be enough space. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Rmano I forget that sometimes people look at the output rather than the log file :-)

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, those users... ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53595/in-table-of-contents-long-page-numbers-intrude-on-right-margin-despite-plenty-o/53597