# Roman page numbering not aligned in table of contents (ToC)

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, alignment, roman-numerals

My page numbering isn't aligned properly `starting with page VIII`. It seems to be somehow focused on the `X`, but also the second chapter isn't aligned properly, where the first, which has arabic numbers, is properly aligned.
Do you have a clue how to solve this?

**MWE.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
        \tableofcontents
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \chapter{Chapter}
                \section{Lorem}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{ipsum}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                        \pagenumbering{Roman}
                \section{dolor}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{sit}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{amet}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{consectetuer}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{adipiscing}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{elit}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{Ut}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
        \chapter{Chapter}
                \section{purus}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{elit}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{vestibulum}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{ut}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
                \section{placerat}
                        \lipsum[1]\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also the following possible duplicate:  [In table of contents, long page numbers intrude on right margin despite plenty of available space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53595/134144) Increasing the space allocated the the page numbers should also resolve the misalignment you see in your example document.

Comment: @leandriis Although it's suggested using `\makeatletter \def\@pnumwidth{50pt}\makeatother` in the preamble, it seems not to work 100 % for page numbering printed bold, but that might be a lot more work to do. So… it's OK for now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to use the `tocloft` package and it's `\cftsecnumwidth{<length>}` to set the space for page numbers. You have to specify the `<length>` argument to suit your document. Below `2em` works for your MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetpnumwidth{2em}  % space for page numbers, default is 1.55em
\begin{document}
% all the rest of your MWE
```

Comment: But then all dots end at a same fixed place, independent of the number width. The behavior is different on the other side. Why having a fix width box is the best design solution?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with a small modification of `\@dottedtocline` (file `latex.ltx`). I added more pages to the MWE to see more Roman letters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
        \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \leavevmode
        \@tempdima #3\relax     
        \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
        {#4}\nobreak
        \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
            \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
            mu$}\hfill
        \nobreak
    %\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
    {\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%  
            \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
        \par}%  
    \fi}    
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents        
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Lorem}
    \lipsum[1-18]\newpage
    \section{ipsum}
    \lipsum[1]\newpage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \section{dolor}
    \lipsum[1-16]\newpage
    \section{sit}
    \lipsum[1-16]\newpage
    \section{amet}
    \lipsum[1]\newpage
    \section{consectetuer}
    \lipsum[1-8]\newpage
    \section{adipiscing}
    \lipsum[1]\newpage
    \section{elit}
    \lipsum[1-15]\newpage
    \section{Ut}
    \lipsum[1]\newpage
\chapter{Chapter 2}
    \section{purus}
    \lipsum[1-14]\newpage
    \section{elit}
    \lipsum[1]\newpage
    \section{vestibulum}
    \lipsum[1-16]\newpage
    \section{ut}
    \lipsum[1-16]\newpage
    \section{placerat}
    \lipsum[1]\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image: x2]

when before it was

[image: x1]

the change replacing

```
 \nobreak
 \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
                    \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
 \par}%
\fi}
```

by

```
 \nobreak
 {\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
                    \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
 \par}%
\fi}
```

*A fixed box does not work.* The alignment also works with

```
\hb@xt@35\p@{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
```

but obviously  the dots do not look so nice with a fixed width, which is the problem with the kind of answers in

[In table of contents, long page numbers intrude on right margin despite plenty of available space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53595/in-table-of-contents-long-page-numbers-intrude-on-right-margin-despite-plenty-o)

[image: x3]

versus

[image: x4]

My TeX is not good enough to go any further.

Comment: With your actual solution, the page numbers of every chapter is shifted some pt to the right…

Comment: @Nepumuk I do not see the effect you are mentioning. Please see the last figure.